# I need help deploying a javascript from within WebView in a JavaFx 2.0 Web App

Tags: javascript, javafx-2

I have a JavaFx 2.0 web application in which there is a Webview component that displays a twitter widget.

When the Application loads in the browser it doesn't show the twitter box.

It only works from the desktop, when I launch the app from the desktop all is well.

Here is the code for the widget:

Update: I had another WebView component in the application and it is working fine, it referenced a .js file locally. I decided to download the source for the other javascript and reference it locally. It didn't work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>templates</title>
<meta name="author" content="Artur Vieira" />
<!-- Date: 2011-12-13 -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="twitter"><script type="text/javascript" src="widget.js" language="javascript"></script> <script>
                    new TWTR.Widget({
                     version: 2,
                     type: 'search',
                     search: 'Nestroia',
                     interval: 6000,
                     title: 'Nestroia on Twitter',
                     subject: 'Follow Us on Twitter',
                     width: 80,
                     height: 250,
                     theme: {
                       shell: {
                         background: '#5584a3',
                         color: '#fff'
                       },
                       tweets: {
                         background: '#fff',
                         color: '#696966',
                         links: '#000'
                       }
                     },
                     features: {
                       scrollbar: false,
                       loop: true,
                       live: true,
                       hashtags: true,
                       timestamp: true,
                       avatars: true,
                       behavior: 'default'
                     }
                    }).render().start();
                </script>

            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the code for the WebView inside the JavaFX 2.0 web application

```
    Group block4 = new Group();
    block4.setLayoutX(740);
    block4.setLayoutY(180);
    WebView webTwitter = new WebView();
    webTwitter.setMinSize(158, 390);
    webTwitter.setPrefSize(158, 390);
    final WebEngine eng2 = webTwitter.getEngine();
    eng2.load("http://www.nestroia.com/twitter.html");
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's very nice. Now, please tell us what problem you're having.

Comment: Just edited. Basically the twitter box doesnt show up.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's error console for any errors? You might also want to check to see if any AJAX requests are made to Twitter using Firebug or Chrome's console.

Comment: K thanks. the twitter box is working fine by itself www.nestroia.com/twitter.html It is only when i put it inside the application that it doesn't show up

Comment: I got a error recently while I was testing the page, it said that the browser cannot access the external URL. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using an absolute URL lik `/twitter.html` without the domain part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that jnlp/plugin applications are being run in Sandbox and has security limitations. And accessing another domain falls under security violation for unsigned apps. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/index.html

To avoid Sandbox you can sign your application:

- in case of NetBeans project go to `Project Properties->Build->Deployment->Unrestricted access->Self-signed jar`
- otherwise read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html

If this doesn't help, please, enable Java Console for browser and show us the output:
`Control Panel->Java->Advanced->Java Console->Show Console`

Comment: I signed the jar file and now the app isnt working. It does not deploy.

Comment: I enabled the console and there is not much that comes up when I run the app, no errors from the console. The browser displays this message."JavaFX application could not launch due to system configuration. See java.com/javafx for troubleshooting information."

Comment: Sounds weird. Can you, please, uninstall JavaFX (both SDK and runtime). Download latest 2.0.2 and reinstall it.

Comment: I have JavaFX 2.0.2 installed with jdk 7u2. Working with Netbeans 7.1 Release Candidate 2. To sign I went to the properties folder as you told me and checked the box that requests unlimited access.